# C# join 3 tabelas utilizando Linq?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Estou pegando para aprender C# e estou apanhando em alguns pontos.

Eu tenho 3 Tabelas.

Seguem as models

```
public class Tag
{
    [Key]
    public int ID_Tag { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o Nome")]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Nome_Tag { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public class Local
{
    [Key]
    public int ID_Local { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o Nome")]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Nome_Local { get; set; }
    public string Tipo_Local { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public class LocTag
{
    [Key]
    public int ID_LocTag { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("Tags")]
    public int ID_Tags { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("Locais")]
    public int ID_Local { get; set; }

    public virtual Tag Tags { get; set; }
    public virtual Local Locais { get; set; }
}
```

e gostaria de fazer o retorno do `SQL` me retornar do seguinte modo.

```
"result":[ {  
         "Locais" :  { 
                        ID_Local, 
                        Nome_Local, 
                        Tag: [{ 
                              ID_Tag, 
                              Nome_Tag }]
                      }  
           }]
```

Eu tentei de varios modos alguns ficaram bem proximos, porem não do jeito que eu pretendia.

```
var result = db.LocTag.Where(x => x.Locais.Tipo_Local == Nome).ToList();
```

me da o seguinte retorno:

```
"result": [
        {
            "Locais": {
                "ID_Local": 5,
                "Nome_Local": "NOME'
            },
            "Tags": {
                "ID_Tag": 1,
                "Nome_Tag": "NOME_TAG"
            },
            "ID_LocTag": 1,
            "ID_Tags": 1,
            "ID_Local": 5
        },....}]
```

Comment: Você não consegue porque a entidade Local não tem a chave de Tag, perceba que apenas LocTag que conhece Tag. Por favor compartilhe conosco as suas entidades para maior detalhe.

Comment: @GabrielColetta adicionei no edit ali.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa acrescentar um Select depois do Where criado a estrutura que você deseja, abaixo segue um exemplo com classe anônima:

```
var result = db.LocTag.Where(x => x.Locais.Tipo_Local == Nome)
    .Select(c =>  new { 
                          ID_Local = c.Locais.ID_Local, 
                          Nome_Local = c.Locais.Nome_Local, 
                          Tag = c.Tags 
                       }).ToList();
```

Aqui outro exemplo onde criei uma classe para representar a estrutura:

```
public class Locais
{
    public int ID_Local { get; set; }
    public string Nome_Local { get; set; }
    public Tag Tag { get; set; }
}
```

Novamente executo o mesmo comando mas neste caso preencho a classe acima:

```
 var result = db.LocTag.Where(x => x.Locais.Tipo_Local == Nome)
      .Select(c => new Locais { 
                                  ID_Local = c.Locais.ID_Local, 
                                  Nome_Local = c.Locais.Nome_Local, 
                                  Tag = c.Tags 
                              }).ToList();
```

Espero ter ajudo, qualquer dúvida estou à disposição.

Comment: Fiz como me indicou, porem ele esta vindo um pouco fora do que eu estou tentando conseguir. 
Adicionei em o retorno do seu exemplo na sua resposta.

Comment: Crie dois exemplos abaixo, qual dos dois atende?

Comment: var result = db.LocTag.Where(x => x.Locais.Tipo_Local == Nome)
                .Select(c => new { Locais = new {
                    ID_Local = c.Locais.ID_Local,
                    Nome_Local = c.Locais.Nome_Local,
                    Tag = c.Tags
                } }).ToList();

Comment: var res = db.LocTag.Where(x => x.Locais.Tipo_Local == Nome)
                .Select(c => new {
                    ID_Local = c.Locais.ID_Local,
                    Nome_Local = c.Locais.Nome_Local,
                    Tag = c.Tags
                }).ToList();

            var result = new { Locais = res };

Comment: Me avisa assim vou alterar a resposta

Comment: Perdão pela demora na resposta, estava sem internet. Os retornos não atenderam o modelo que eu necessitava no retorno. Utilizei um for each para aninhar o retorno que você me deu com o modelo que necessitava como medida para dar continuidade nos meus estudos.

Comment: Beleza cara, qualquer dúvida estou à disposição